# Why doesn't .filter in Redux reducer modify state in whereas .push does?

Tags: redux, react-redux

In my class I learned that it's a rule that reducers in Redux are not allowed to directly modify the original state and then provided two examples. The first used a .filter method to return an altered state while the second example used a .push method to return an altered state. My source says the first example follows these rules that reducers are not allowed to directly modify the original state whereas the second breaks this rule. I don't understand why the line with "case 'songs/removeSong' " in the first example is allowed to filter the state array, whereas the "case 'songs/addGlobalSong' " in the second example using the .push method breaks this rule:

(First example)

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type){
case 'songs/addSong': {
return [...state, action.payload]
}
case 'songs/removeSong': {
return state.filter(song => song !== action.payload)
}
default:
return state;
}
}
```

(second example)

```
const playlistReducer = (state = [], action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case 'songs/addGlobalSong': {
state.push(action.payload)
return state
}
default:
return state;
}
}
```

I know we're supposed to use the spread operator instead in our return statement as not to influence the original array (like return [...state, action.payload] ), I just don't understand why the .filter method is not considered influencing the original array whereas the .push method is considered affecting the original array. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter returns a subset of the original array based on a given condition whereas push method makes changes to the array for which it is called.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense! Filter doesn't change the original array but creates a shallow copy of it. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: If this clears the question, mark the question as answered. Thanks